# Ошибка в PHP SIMPLE HTML DOM PARSER

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Использую библиотеку PHP SIMPLE HTML DOM PARSER,
имеется следующий код:

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
```

При заходе на localhost/
выдает ошибку, как решить:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking in C:\xampp\htdocs\Parser\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to seek to position -1 in the stream in C:\xampp\htdocs\Parser\simple_html_dom.php on line 75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала загрузите страницу в переменную, хотя бы через тот же самый `file_get_contents()`, а затем используйте `str_get_html()` для получения DOM из этой переменной.

Причина ошибки (для функции `file_get_contents()` в библиотеке):

> Поиск смещения (offset) не поддерживается при работе с удаленными файлами. Попытка поиска смещения на нелокальных файлах может работать при небольших смещениях, но результат будет непредсказуемым, так как функция работает на буферизованном потоке.

Comment: <?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$object = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
$b = str_get_html($object);
Правильно?

Comment: @ГромСупиев, да. Только гугл по http давно не работает уже.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!

Comment: вылезло при переходе с 5.6 на 7.1 на IIS, интересно.

Answer (score 0):

Включите в php.ini `allow_url_fopen` Передав значение 1, иначе стороннике URL блокируются.

Comment: Включен allow_url_fopen=On не получается все равно, пробовал так тоже allow_url_fopen=1